# Windows scattered across virtual desktops after waking up from sleep

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, suspend, window-manager, window

My setup is two external screens connected to a docking station and the laptop
screen all running (thanks, Lenovo!). I have four virtual desktops (Ubuntu 14.04, Unity).
At any point I might have one to two dozens windows open, carefully organised 
across the virtual desktops and screens.

Now, every time I put my laptop to sleep and wake it up again (it remains connected
to the docking station for the whole time), the windows are no longer where they were.

I *could* understand if Unity forgot the position on each desktop, maybe because
it detects the additional screens after positioning the windows on the laptop
screen alone. However, the windows are also scattered across the virtual desktops
with no recognisable pattern: windows from any desktop may end up on any other,
and on other screens as well.

What is happening here and how do I fix it?

Bonus question: do other window/desktop managers have the same problem?

Comment: I'm sorry Raphael, your question is too old for me to migrate, you'll have to re-ask it on [unix.se].